# How to point one array to another array

Tags: c++

I have two arrays in a class, both with different sizes. My goal is to copy the second array (nArray) to the the first array (_theArray) using pointers. Below I have included the code of the function in the class, as well as the function in main to test the swap.

I have written the code below, where I try to point the first array to the second array using pointer p (int * p).

```
void easyArray::resize(unsigned int newSize)
{
    // created new dynamic array
    int * nArray = new int[newSize];

    // init the new array
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        nArray[i] = 0;
        cout << nArray[i] << " ";
    }
    if (newSize >= _size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            nArray[i] = _theArray[i]; 
        }
    } else {
        cout << "not enough room" << endl;
    }

    destroy(); //deletes old array

    int *p = _theArray; //points old to new array (?)
    p = nArray; //sets old array = to new array (?)

}
```

in main:

```
void testResize()
{
    easyArray a(5); 

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a[i] = i + 100; 
    }

    a.resize(10); 

    a[9] = 99; 

    cout << "TEST RESIZE: " << a << endl << endl; 
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Currently when I run this I get the error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Expression:_CrtIsValiedHeadPointer(block)

Comment: Think about those assignments at the end of `resize`. First you make `p` point to `_theArray`, then you make `p` point to `nArray`. That's it. How could you make `_theArray` point to `nArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `_theArray` is a class member variable, you can do `_theArray = nArray` after the call to `destroy()` and delete the last 2 lines involving `p`.